# Computing Standard Deviation without packages in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, statistics, opencsv, standard-deviation

I'm trying to figure out how to create a script which calculates a standard deviation for a file. As an example, say I DLed a csv with a list of values on it. I want to find the SD of these values by running a python program. We are not using numpy here!

Comment: So where exactly are you stuck? The formula is quite simple.

Answer (score 11):

If you allow the use of the standard library,

```py
import math

xs = [0.5,0.7,0.3,0.2]     # values (must be floats!)
mean = sum(xs) / len(xs)   # mean
var  = sum(pow(x-mean,2) for x in xs) / len(xs)  # variance
std  = math.sqrt(var)  # standard deviation
```

If not, you need to approximate `sqrt` by hand. For example, you can use binary search or [Newton's Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). Here's a [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots) for methods of doing so

Comment: ahhh well its because I am importing data which is messy in the sense that it is not given to me in a straight list. It has commas, spaces, and other numbers which i don't care about. I am only interested in one column. I have to change it so that it is the optimum list where we can easily perform the functions you've written. Figuring how to even import it has been a struggle

Answer (score 5):

with Python 3.4 and above there is a package called statistics, that has [standard deviation (pstdev)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.pstdev) and other functions

Here is an example of how to use it:

```
import statistics

data = [1, 1, 2.5, 6.5, 7.3, 8, 9.2]

print(statistics.pstdev(data))
# 3.2159043543498815
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 from math import sqrt
 n= [11, 8, 8, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8] 

 mean =sum(n)/len(n)
 SUM= 0
 for i in n :
     SUM +=(i-mean)**2



 stdeV = sqrt(SUM/(len(n)-1)) 
 print(stdeV)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filename = "C:\Users\mmb0368\Desktop\input.txt"
file = open("C:\Users\mmb0368\Desktop\input.txt","rb")

n = file.readlines()

num_list = map(lambda n: n.rstrip("\n"), n)
num_list = [int(x) for x in num_list]
mean = sum(num_list)/len(num_list)
print mean, max(num_list), min(num_list)

for snDev in num_list:

    snDev = mean**(1.0/2)
print snDev
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import sqrt

def getAverage(mylist):
    """
    This function calculates the average of a list of numbers.

    Parameters:
    mylist (list): List of numbers

    Returns:
    float: Average of the numbers in the list

    Example:
    >>> getAverage([1,5,10])
    5.333333333333333
    """
    return sum(mylist)/len(mylist)

def getStandardDeviation(mylist):
    """
    This function calculates the standard deviation of a list of numbers.

    Parameters:
    mylist (list): List of numbers

    Returns:
    float: Standard deviation of the numbers in the list

    Example:
    >>> getStandardDeviation([1,5,10])
    4.509249752822894
    """
    ls=[]
    for i in mylist:
        ls.append((i - getAverage(mylist))**2)
    return sqrt( sum(ls) / (len(mylist) - 1) )

mylist = [1,5,10]

getAverage(mylist=mylist)
# 5.333333333333333

getStandardDeviation(mylist=mylist)
# 4.509249752822894
```

This code contains two functions `getAverage` and `getStandardDeviation` for calculating average and standard deviation of a list of numbers respectively. The `getAverage` function takes in a list of numbers and returns the average of those numbers. The `getStandardDeviation` function takes in a list of numbers and returns the standard deviation of those numbers by first finding the square difference of each number from the average and then taking the square root of the average of those squared differences. A sample list `mylist` of numbers is defined at the end and both functions are called with this list as argument.

Comment: Please add explanations.

Comment: @Ego code only answer is not ideal, please add details to improve your answer's clarity

Answer (score 0):

```
def calculateSD(self, nums):
    n = len(nums)
    mean = sum(nums) // n
    variance = sum((x - mean) ** 2 for x in nums) / (n - 1)

    stdev = variance ** 0.5
    print(stdev)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste function for you.

```
def standard_dev(nums):
standard_deviation = (sum([(num - calc_mean(nums)) ** 2 for num in nums]) / len(nums)) ** (1/2)
return standard_deviation
```

Here's a more spread out function if you only want to calculate to variance.

```
def standard_dev(nums):
sum_diff_sq = sum([(num - calc_mean(nums))**2 for num in nums])
variance = sum_diff_sq / len(nums)
standard_deviation = variance ** (1/2)
return standard_deviation
```

Answer (score 0):

The formula for standard deviation is σ = √Σ(x-µ)² / √N
where µ is mean(colloquially average here), x is each data. Σ(x-µ)² means each data should be subtracted by mean and squared and the the resultant of this of all data should be added.√Σ(x-µ)² indicates square root is taken for the added value.

N in the denominator is the total population. √N indicates square root should be taken. (You may find a single square root for both numerator and Denominator in the maths textbooks. I split into two. The reason is both are one and the same. And with the available alt code, It will be easy to understand only if I do like this.)

Please note: If it is just sample population, the denominator will be √(N-1)

Now we'll go step by step:

```
values = [5,4,3,6,7,2]

# the lenth of the value is the total population
N = len(values)

#mean is nothing but adding all values and divide by total numbers
mean = sum(values)/N

# finding (x-µ)² part- create a list with each value subtracted by mean and squared
NrSqr = [(x-mean)**2 for x in values]

# finding Σ portion which is nothing but all values sum
Sigma = sum(NrSqr)

#Square root to be taken for the sum
Nr = Sigma ** (1/2)

#taking square root to N for denominator
Dr = N ** (1/2)

#Find out standard deviation
sd = Nr/Dr

#round off to 2 decimals if required
sd = round(sd, 2)

#Get output
print(sd)
```

When you want to read from csv file and find out standard deviation, import csv module.

```
import csv
with open('names.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    sumAndIndex = (0,0)
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        #let us imagine the header i.e first row for data is 'data'
        x = row['data']
        sumAndIndex = (sumAndIndex[0]+x, sumAndIndex[1]+i)
    #now the total population is sumAndIndex[1]+1 as the index start from 0
    N = sumAndIndex[1]+1
    mean = sumAndIndex[0]/N
```

The rest of the calculations are as same as the previous code I provided. As this is just a pseudocode, when you want repeat thge operation with multiple files, you can create a function with file being the argument:

```
def standard_deviation(file):
```